# What job does vscode file watcher do?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I met error "Visual Studio Code is unable to watch for file changes in this large workspace" when I  work on a remote server. The solution to this problem is here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux#_visual-studio-code-is-unable-to-watch-for-file-changes-in-this-large-workspace-error-enospc

As I do not have permission to edit /etc/sysctl.conf to increase the limit, I have to exclude some directories from file watcher. I wonder what job does vscode file watcher do, and what happens if certain files are not tracked by the file watcher? So far I think file watcher is not so important so it should be safe to exclude files from file watcher?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: One job of the fileWatcher is to detect changes to those files you may make in another application.  You would want to know if any opened files were changed elsewhere.